# Fiberglass Bathtub Wall Slanted Down - Slip on Faucet Gap Too Large to Fix with Caulk

Tags: faucet, bathtub, gap, fiberglass

Copper stub-out with a slip-on faucet that requires a minimum 1.75 inch length. The bottom-half of the faucet base fits flush against the fiberglass tub wall, but there is a significant gap between the top-half base of the faucet and the wall. The old faucet had a crap-ton of caulk to fill the gap. A decorative ring between the faucet base and wall n a fix.did not fix the problem. I'm open for suggestions on a fix.

Comment: Adding a picture would help.

Comment: Either going to need to file/grind something to fit, or move the spout to a more suitable (flat) location. As best I can guess with no picture, anyway.